# Split a list of unknown size lists into a dataframe with n no. of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, nested-lists

Given a list of list with unknown size of the inner list, e.g.:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> lol = [[1,2,3], [3,1,1], [3,2], [1], [2,3,4]]
>>> sr = pd.Series(lol)
>>> sr
0    [1, 2, 3]
1    [3, 1, 1]
2       [3, 2]
3          [1]
4    [2, 3, 4]
dtype: object
```

**How to split the list into 3 lists?** If the list has less than 3 populate the list with `None`

The goal is to get a dataframe with 3 columns from the 3 lists, i.e.:

```
   0    1    2
0  1  2.0  3.0
1  3  1.0  1.0
2  3  2.0  NaN
3  1  NaN  NaN
4  2  3.0  4.0
```

I've tried doing this:

```
lol = [[1,2,3], [3,1,1], [3,2], [1], [2,3,4]]
sr = pd.Series(lol)

df = []
n = 3
for row in sr:
    while len(row) < n:
        row.append(None)
    df.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
```

[out]:

```
    0   1   2
0   1   2.0 3.0
1   3   1.0 1.0
2   3   2.0 NaN
3   1   NaN NaN
4   2   3.0 4.0
```

**Is there a simpler way to achieve the same dataframe?**

**Is there an easier way to achieve the same final dataframe if the `n` is unknown before hand?**

**Is doing `max(len(row) for row in sr)` the only way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pd.DataFrame` constructor can handle that fine.

```
lol = [[1,2,3], [3,1,1], [3,2], [1], [2,3,4]]

pd.DataFrame(lol)

   0    1    2
0  1  2.0  3.0
1  3  1.0  1.0
2  3  2.0  NaN
3  1  NaN  NaN
4  2  3.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
In [149]: sr.apply(pd.Series)
Out[149]:
     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  3.0  1.0  1.0
2  3.0  2.0  NaN
3  1.0  NaN  NaN
4  2.0  3.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert Series to `numpy array` and then to `list`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sr.values.tolist())
print (df)

   0    1    2
0  1  2.0  3.0
1  3  1.0  1.0
2  3  2.0  NaN
3  1  NaN  NaN
4  2  3.0  4.0
```

If input is nested list, better is [piRSquared's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46640237/2901002).

Comment: Thanks for the added comment @jezrael!